Doorbell circuit breaker
Is it possible for the doorbell transformer to have its own cicuit breaker while having another circuit breaker for the doorbell wire?
I turned off the circuit breaker for the doorbell bell but the transformer still had power.

Technically possible, but just as likely you have 2 different transformers.

Or you turned off the wrong breaker.

The doorbell wire is low voltage. It doesn't have a breaker.  There is only a breaker for whatever circuit the transformer is tied into.

I closed the circuit breaker for the foyer and the doorbell light went out. I then checked the transformer and it was reading 18 volts.
This is strange!

You might be looking at the wrong transformer. Often, heating-ventilation-air conditioning (HVAC) system have their own 18-24 VAC transformers, as do alarm systems and other low-voltage appliances.
